# Programmatically get mail address of spreadsheet creator

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a small bot program that, among other things, publishes spreadsheets to Google Sheets in a certain format, and attempts to retrieve them back on command. For security reasons, however, I need to ensure that it was the bot itself that created said spreadsheet before attempting to parse it back.

I have located *extremely roundabout* ways to go at it - such as running a Google Apps Script to attempt to add and remove everyone to the editors list of a protected range, as per [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/88575/how-to-retrieve-email-address-of-current-user) - but that seems rather difficult and unintuitive. Is there any reasonable way to retrieve the creator's credentials - the service Gmail address, for instance?

**Update:** A bit of asking around has led me to a hypothesis that a protected range created by the spreadsheet's administrator will only have that user as the owner, while a protected range created by anyone else will include the editor and the owner (be it an attempt at forgery in an authentic spreadsheet, or in a spreadsheet created by someone else - the roles swap depending on either scenario). That could be used to verify; luckily, the bot already includes a protected range within its sheets. I have not tested that hypothesis, however, and would be glad to see a more explicit/elegant solution.

Comment: Have you tried to use [Spreadsheet.getOwner()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getOwner()) method? The owner object has `getEmail()` method.

Comment: As a matter of fact, I have not, and have only just now noticed that the method exists (seconds before actually returning to this question). Reading is not my strong suit, evidently. Thank you! Would upvote the comment if I could.

Answer (score 0):

See comment on the question proper. I could use a better attention span, it seems.